# How to merge two python environments?

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa

I have this wierd requirement where I have 2 modules

- chatbot(using rasa)
- image classifier

I want to create a single `Flask` Web service for both of them

But issue is `RASA` uses `tensorflow` 1.x while my image classifier module is built using `tensorflow` 2.x.

I know I can not have both versions of Tensorflow in my environment(if there's a way, i am not aware of it)

As RASA doesn't support Tensorflow 2.x yet, one thing I'm left with is to downgrade Tensorflow for image classifier.

Is there a way to tackle this issue without changing my existing code or with minimum changes?

Comment: You could keep them as distinct apps in distinct envs, and set up some IPC between them.

Comment: will IPC allow me to run both these as single Flask APP?

Comment: "IPC" means "inter process communication" - you will of course need twi distinct processes, each running in it's own virtualenv. But that will be transparent for your end users, just like the communication between a Flask app and a RDBMS or Redis db etc...